# Native iOS Unity Integration - AppStore Provisioning Profile causes 'UnityFramework/UnityFramework.h' file not found

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unity-game-engine

I have a native iOS app (Swift) with Unity integrated as a library following this guide:
https://forum.unity.com/threads/integration-unity-as-a-library-in-native-ios-app.685219/

XCode 12.5.1, Unity 2019.4.12f, CocoaPods 1.10.2

For the last 3 days, I am getting this error when I attempt to archive with an AppStore provisioning profile:

> /Users/../Bridging-Header.h:9:9: 'UnityFramework/UnityFramework.h'
> file not found
>
> Failed to emit precompiled header
> '/Users/../Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/appname-testflight-qa/PrecompiledHeaders/Bridging-Header-swift_OMITED-clang_OMITED.pch'
> for bridging header '/Users/../Bridging-Header.h'

When I do a regular build using any Provisioning Profile (PP), it builds successfully and I can run on device. When I archive using an Ad-Hoc PP, it succeeds as well.
It only happens during archiving using a manually specified AppStore PP, which I need for doing command-line builds for automated deployments. I've confirmed it happens in both commandline and in XCode editor. I need the Bridging Header so that I can allow native iOS to interact with Unity to pass it some information.

Here's the bridging header:

```
#ifndef BRIDGING_HEADER
#define BRIDGING_HEADER

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <UnityFramework/UnityFramework.h>
#import <UnityFramework/NativeCallProxy.h>

#endif /* BRIDGING_HEADER */
```

I've tried the following suggestions already on all the other UnityFramework.h not found questions to no avail:

1. Switch off Parallize Build
2. Add UnityFramework.framework and/or Unity-iPhone project as a target first in the build process
3. Cleaned up project, delete DerivedData, deleted/reinstalled Pods
4. Switched to another scheme that will archive an Ad-Hoc PP, and changed to using AppStore PP
5. Reintegrated the Unity project all-over again
6. Build target set to Device (not simulator) through all these tests
7. I tried switching to: "../UnityFramework/UnityFramework.h" inside the Bridging header
8. Made Framework optional inside Build Phases - Link Binary With Libraries (and tried to add Copy File Build Phase - this caused an error saying this copy step was being duplicated)
9. Validated Runpath already includes @executable_path/Frameworks
10. Tried changing Pods and Project to iOS 12.1 min version and set Pods' Build Active Architecture Only to YES

Any help or suggestions would be very appreciated. I'm completely out of ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue resided with naming of Configurations between the primary project and the Unity-iPhone subproject. Since the Unity project didn't have a matching configuration, it chose from one of the other available configurations, in my case, Debug (QA). When the archive went looking for the UnityFramework, it was in the wrong folder.

Essentially, if you have custom Configurations, make sure all of them in your primary project are also in the Unity-iPhone Project with exact same name.